# php mysql input script with check

Tags: php, mysql

ive a problem with my input script. the check grind are broken and dont work right now.

The Script should look for the get over and should check it with db support.

In my case, the while grind are buggy.... they dont work right....

```
<?php


    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');

    $mysqli = new MySQLi("localhost", "dbuser", "dbpass", "clantools");
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ({$mysqli->connect_errno}) {$mysqli->connect_error}";
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM clanmember_ra1se where '".$_GET['account_name']."' = Playername");

    //while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    //  {
    //
    //      if ($_GET['clantag'] = $row['Clantag']) {

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0)
    {


            echo '
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
            <title>Code Eingabe</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <form action="?" method="get">
              <input type="hidden" name="account_name" value="'.$_GET['account_name'].'">
              <input type="hidden" name="clantag" value="'.$_GET['clantag'].'">
              <input type="hidden" name="role" value="'.$_GET['role'].'">
              <input type="hidden" name="role_i18n" value="'.$_GET['role_i18n'].'">
              <p>Code: <input type="text" name="code" /></p>
              <p><input type="radio" name="activity" id="leitend" value="leitend" />Leitender FK</p>
              <p><input type="radio" name="activity" id="gespielt" value="gespielt" />Gespielt</p>
              <p><input type="radio" name="activity" id="bereit" value="bereit" />Bereit</p>
              <p><input type="submit" name="absenden" value="Code senden"/></p>
            </form>

            </body>
            </html>
            ';

            if ( empty ($_GET['code']) != TRUE and isset($_GET['absenden']))
                {
                    // wenn beide Bedingungen zutreffen, 
                    // dann folgende Anweisungen ausführen

                    if (isset ($_GET['activity'])){
                         if ($_GET['activity']=="leitend"){
                              $status = 'leitend';
                         }
                         if ($_GET['activity']=="gespielt"){
                              $status = 'gespielt';
                         }
                         if ($_GET['activity']=="bereit"){
                              $status = 'bereit';
                         }
                    }
                    $eingabe = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());


                    //$mysqli = new MySQLi("localhost", "dbuser", "dbpass", "clantools");
                    //if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
                    //      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ({$mysqli->connect_errno}) {$mysqli->connect_error}";
                    //}

                    $result_code = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM code_ra1se where '".$_GET['code']."' = code");



                    if (mysqli_num_rows($result_code) != 0)
                        {
                            echo '<br>';
                            echo '<center>Code wird gepr&uuml;ft</center>';
                            echo "<br>";
                            echo "<br>";
                            echo "<br>";
                            echo "<br>"; 

                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_code))
                         {


                            $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM eingabe_code_ra1se where '".$_GET['account_name']."' = spielername");

                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                                {

                                    if ($_GET['code'] != $row['code'] {





                                    //echo ''.$row['gueltigkeit'].' > '.$eingabe.''; 

                                    if ($row_code['gueltigkeit'] > $eingabe){



                                        $sql = "INSERT INTO eingabe_code_ra1se (spielername,code,clantag,eingabezeit,role,role_i18n,activity ) VALUES ('".$_GET['account_name']."', '".$_GET['code']."', '".$_GET['clantag']."', '".$eingabe."', '".$_GET['role']."', '".$_GET['role_i18n']."', '".$status."')";

                                        if ($mysqli->query($sql) == TRUE) {
                                                echo "<b><center>Code erfolgreich &uuml;bermittelt!</center><br> BITTE SEITE SCHLIE&szlig;EN!!</b> <br>";
                                        } else {
                                                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $mysqli->error;
                                        }

                                        $mysqli->close();

                                        } else {


                                            echo "<b><center>Code ist nicht g&uuml;ltig!</center></b> <br>";

                                        }

                                    } else {

                                            echo "<b><center>Du hast den Code breits eingegeben!</center></b> <br>";

                                    }

                                }

                            }
                            }  else {

                                    echo "<b><center>Der Code existiert nicht!</center></b> <br>";

                            }
                }
        } else {

            echo "<b><center>Du bist nicht berechtigt den Code hier einzugeben!</center></b> <br>";

        }

?>
```

The problem of this scripts are the while grind. how can i make this easier?
i think the most of the while grind are usless.....

Comment: `if ($_GET['code'] != $row['code'] {` is missing a closing bracket `)`

Comment: please use prepared statements before going into production with this

Comment: the closing bracket is this } else {

          echo "<b><center>Du hast den Code breits eingegeben!</center></b> <br>";

        }

Comment: What is your question? Spaghetti-code code is terrible thing, this is always mean a lot of time to debugging and understanding what code should do.

Comment: the question is, how can i make this script to work. i have to many while {}.... and yes i know its spaghetti-code. im not a fully developer.... thats my problem.

Comment: the script stops by the answer "code wird überprüft"....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the line,

```
if ($_GET['code'] != $row['code'] {
```

with this,

```
if ($_GET['code'] != $row['code']) {
```

You have forgotten to close the `if` statement.

```
if (condition) {
    code to be executed if condition is true;
}
```